# Floated image overflows parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to `float:right;` image next to paragraph `<p>`, which are nested together in `<div>` container. The problem is that the parent `<div>` resize its `height` with the size of the text in the paragraph, that's good, but floated right image overflows the div, and same `<div>` didn't resize itself according to the `image height`.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #777;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.content .container {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  /*
  overflow: hidden; /* Try later without overflow. (autoportrait.jpg overflow .content .container
  */
}
.autoportrait {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  /*
  max-width:205px;
  max-height:265px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  */
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <!--
    <main>
    <section>
    -->
    <img class="autoportrait" src="autoportrait.jpg" alt="Autoportrait of me">
    <h2>Post title</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu purus et enim eleifend fringilla. Cras nec tortor elementum, vestibulum orci id, congue nisl. Fusce ornare ac turpis sit amet tincidunt. Phasellus vel magna ut massa tempus ultricies.
      Etiam erat libero, molestie vitae scelerisque quis, consequat eget lorem. Nulla finibus felis non mi viverra efficitur. Proin eget lobortis libero. Fusce aliquam eros sed placerat viverra. Nulla venenatis, nulla sit amet suscipit vulputate, sem
      mauris rutrum erat, id pharetra dui nunc at dui. Morbi dignissim luctus maximus. Cras vitae ornare risus. Sed accumsan vitae eros ac placerat. Proin commodo non orci nec consectetur. Nunc posuere, enim a lobortis ultrices, augue ex ultrices ante,
      nec consectetur elit leo a ligula. Mauris pellentesque massa nisl, non pellentesque ex pulvinar eu.
    </p>
    <!--
    </section>
    </main>
    -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use `overflow: hidden;` , but that works only for a single "post". When I try to put a second one, the same problem appears and length of the images that flows out of the 'content container' doubles.
   I'm newbie in HTML/CSS and the code I write it's for my own knowledge. So I'll be grateful if we figure out something.

Greetings from Varna, Bulgaria!

Comment: I currently don't see/understand the issue, it looks like the text is wrapping the image properly while the image resizes.

Comment: @hungerstar  you'll see it when the text is only one or two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Make the div to clear it's children using `:after` pseudo class.

```css
.container{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #777;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.content .container {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    /*overflow: hidden; /* Try later without overflow. (autoportrait.jpg overflow .content .container) */
}

.autoportrait{
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    /*max-width:205px;
    max-height:265px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;*/
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    float: right;
    clear:both;
}

.container:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display:table;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
            <!--<main>
                    <section>-->    
                        <img class="autoportrait" src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg" alt="Autoportrait of me">
                        <h2>Post title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu purus et enim eleifend fringilla. 
   </p>
                <!--</section>
                </main>-->
            </div>
  <div class="container">
            <!--<main>
                    <section>-->    
                        <img class="autoportrait" src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg" alt="Autoportrait of me">
                        <h2>Post title</h2>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu purus et enim eleifend fringilla. 
                        Cras nec tortor elementum, vestibulum orci id, congue nisl. Fusce ornare ac turpis sit amet tincidunt. 
                        Phasellus vel magna ut massa tempus ultricies. Etiam erat libero, molestie vitae scelerisque quis, consequat eget lorem. 
                        Nulla finibus felis non mi viverra efficitur. Proin eget lobortis libero. Fusce aliquam eros sed placerat viverra. 
                        Nulla venenatis, nulla sit amet suscipit vulputate, sem mauris rutrum erat, id pharetra dui nunc at dui. 
                        Morbi dignissim luctus maximus. Cras vitae ornare risus. Sed accumsan vitae eros ac placerat. 
                        Proin commodo non orci nec consectetur. Nunc posuere, enim a lobortis ultrices, augue ex ultrices ante, nec consectetur elit leo a ligula. 
                        Mauris pellentesque massa nisl, non pellentesque ex pulvinar eu.
                        </p>
                <!--</section>
                </main>-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can improve your pseudo element to `:after { content: ''; display: table; clear: both; }`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I've updated it. I've never been that comfortable with `table` so I wanna ask what exactly will that do, compared to `block`

Comment: Well, I think they're fairly similar. `table` is block level but will only expand to its content's width were `block` will take up 100% of parent width. Other than that the main difference is how it handles child elements. The formula above is used by a lot of CSS frameworks and made famous [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion kittyCat. I'm replying lil bit late but, I got to understand ::after selector and the other properties you have written in the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use `overflow: hidden;` on `.content .container`.

I know you said you attempted it previously and even had it commented out in `.content .container` but it's working for me. Perhaps the issue was where/how you placed the second article in your markup.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #777;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.content .container {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.autoportrait {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  /*
  max-width:205px;
  max-height:265px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  */
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="autoportrait" src="http://placehold.it/300x500/fc0/" alt="Autoportrait of me">
    <h2>Post title</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu purus et enim eleifend fringilla. Cras nec tortor elementum, vestibulum orci id, congue nisl. Fusce ornare ac turpis sit amet tincidunt. Phasellus vel magna ut massa tempus ultricies.
      Etiam erat libero, molestie vitae scelerisque quis, consequat eget lorem. Nulla finibus felis non mi viverra efficitur. Proin eget lobortis libero. Fusce aliquam eros sed placerat viverra. Nulla venenatis, nulla sit amet suscipit vulputate, sem
      mauris rutrum erat, id pharetra dui nunc at dui. Morbi dignissim luctus maximus. Cras vitae ornare risus. Sed accumsan vitae eros ac placerat. Proin commodo non orci nec consectetur. Nunc posuere, enim a lobortis ultrices, augue ex ultrices ante,
      nec consectetur elit leo a ligula. Mauris pellentesque massa nisl, non pellentesque ex pulvinar eu.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="autoportrait" src="http://placehold.it/300x500/fc0/" alt="Autoportrait of me">
    <h2>Post title</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu purus et enim eleifend fringilla. Cras nec tortor elementum, vestibulum orci id, congue nisl. Fusce ornare ac turpis sit amet tincidunt. Phasellus vel magna ut massa tempus ultricies.
      Etiam erat libero, molestie vitae scelerisque quis, consequat eget lorem. Nulla finibus felis non mi viverra efficitur. Proin eget lobortis libero. Fusce aliquam eros sed placerat viverra. Nulla venenatis, nulla sit amet suscipit vulputate, sem
      mauris rutrum erat, id pharetra dui nunc at dui. Morbi dignissim luctus maximus. Cras vitae ornare risus. Sed accumsan vitae eros ac placerat. Proin commodo non orci nec consectetur. Nunc posuere, enim a lobortis ultrices, augue ex ultrices ante,
      nec consectetur elit leo a ligula. Mauris pellentesque massa nisl, non pellentesque ex pulvinar eu.
    </p>
    <!--
    </section>
    </main>
    -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate. But as you already see, in my CSS code I posted earlier, I got written overflow:hidden; and its just commented, because it didnt work properly. Cheers!

Comment: @diyanborisov The thing is, **it does work properly** in Chrome, FF and IE. Run the code snippet above and you can plainly see that it does. Not sure why it "doesn't" for you. What browser are you testing with? Perhaps your CSS and/or markup at the time was slightly different then what you posted here. All it takes is one extra/missing property to throw you off